# How to remove hyphen "-" but count the number before remove the hyphen in C#?

Tags: c#, string, label

I have a textbox, a label and a button, the textbox format like this:

> 23-44-33-32-34-05-40-12

I want when user click the button then remove all the "-" but count each number and store with some string variable and then show the total number or string over the label.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [String.Replace()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: What do you mean by _show the total number_ exactly? You want to get total as `23 + 44 + ...` or you want to count how many digit in your string after you remove all `-` character?

Comment: CeebLaj Thoj - see my answer and comment

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try with this :

```
       //Getting the textbox data and assigning to a string
        string initialstring = textbox1.text;
       //Calculating the total number of words available
        int totalcount = initialstring.Split('-').Length;           
       //Replacing the '-' character which need to be reassign to textbox
        string formattedstring = initialstring.Replace("-", " ");
       //Assigning formatted data to textbox
        textbox1.text = formattedstring;
```

Comment: Too much work for something so simple.

Comment: it works, but how to count all the number before remove the "-"?

Comment: @CeebLaj Thoj , here i am counting the number of words before removing '-' . it returns count as  8

Comment: Hi your code was solved my problem but I have another question is how do I compare each string after remove the "-"?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is first replace the character and then do count on it. You may do like following:

```
var countOfCharacters = mystring.Replace("-", "").Length;
youlabel.Text = countOfCharacters;
```

Answer (score 0):

Very simple:

```
var nrOfChars = yourTextBox.Text.Count(c => c != '-')
```